# Sample code for Azure Media Player

Tags: android, azure-media-services

I have uploaded a video to azure media services which I am able to view in browser. 
Now I want show this video in my android app and should be able to programmatically..

1. Pause
2. Play
3. Jump to particular time.

Will I be able to do this on android? Is there any sample code that can help me in this regard?

Comment: Are you building a native android app or webpage on Android devices? If you are building a native app, which SDK are you using?

Comment: Native would be a more preferred. But I am clueless which SDK to use for playing Azure Videos. If you can advice me in this regard, it would be of great help.

Answer (score 1):

We could deliver either HLS v3 or v4 to Android devices:http://mingfeiy.com/android-hls-playback-via-azure-media-services. You can use Android Native SDK to playback the HLS steam.We don't offer an Android SDK. If you are looking for a web player, you can try our Azure Media Player: http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2015/04/15/announcing-azure-media-player/.